# Regular expression extract product code from URL

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm looking to get a regular expression to match the numeric part of a URL, there could be multiple instances of numbers in the URL, but I'm only looking the id which is always in the format `pid12345.html`

e.g.

```
this-is-a-url-manu-code-mk1234pid98765.html
```

I only want the product code, which is `98765` and nothing else.

Tried `pid(\d+)` which returns the match in the 1st group, but I just want the number returned and nothing else.

Thanks in advance.
Richard

Comment: You know there is `pid` before the number, why not `substr` it after getting a match? Let alone grabbing `match[1]` that you can do with your existing regex.

Comment: Yes, I could, but I would like a clean regex which will capture the match exactly.

Comment: Why is `/pid(\d+)/` unclean? It is just what you need.

Comment: I don't want the pid to be returned.  If I use that I get the following:Full match 26-34 `pid23543`
Group 1. n/a `23543`

Comment: `/(?<=pid)\d+/`?

Comment: Yes! Jeto, that is exactly it, thank you

Comment: The Group 1 start is Match start + 3. Lookbehinds do not work in all browsers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right, seems like it's quite recent (edit: actually unclear, I can't find a source mentioning when it appeared - maybe it's just not purely JS-related). I'll update my answer below (feel free to post yours which is definitely more correct if browser compatibility is to be considered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`/(?<=pid)\d+/`](https://regex101.com/r/cZPE1B/1) should do it (as posted in OP's comments).

**Edit**: as @WiktorStribiżew mentioned, not using lookbehind assertions is probably a better solution if browser/JS engine compatibility is an issue. Refer to his solution in OP's comments if that is the case.